# TTN Integration in Thingsboard PE over MQTTS

Tags: thingsboard

Platform Integration of Thingsboard PE to a private Hosted TTN Server with MQTTS fails.

We have a TB PE hosted on AWS and I am trying to use the Platform Integration over MQTTS (port:8883) to our hosted private TTN Server.

Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to MQTT broker at <mycompany>.thethings.industries:8883.
at org.thingsboard.server.service.integration.mqtt.AbstractMqttIntegration.initClient(AbstractMqttIntegration.java:182)
at org.thingsboard.server.service.integration.mqtt.basic.BasicMqttIntegration.init(BasicMqttIntegration.java:71)
at org.thingsboard.server.service.integration.DefaultPlatformIntegrationService.initIntegration(DefaultPlatformIntegrationService.java:599)
at org.thingsboard.server.service.integration.DefaultPlatformIntegrationService.getOrCreateThingsboardPlatformIntegration(DefaultPlatformIntegrationService.java:579)
at org.thingsboard.server.service.integration.DefaultPlatformIntegrationService.lambda$createIntegration$0(DefaultPlatformIntegrationService.java:245)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Log File Error:

```
2019-09-01 00:02:11,722 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-2] WARN i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Looks like the problem with authentication. Could you check without TLS (plain MQTT)? This will help you to narrow down. Also, you can verify if the certificate is the right one.

Comment: I have checked it without MQTT and it works fine. Also tested SSL from Node-Red and it works fine. So the credentials and the server side are correct. Has anybody tested out this functionality. I see posts most on publishing data to devices on TB with SSL and others but less on outgoing platform integrations.

Comment: Just correcting my post above, I meant I have checked the connection without SSL.